# Невозможность отмены отступов с помощью !important

Tags: html, css3

[image: margin]

Подскажите, откуда этот маргин у параграфа при явном аннулировании его через !important? Из лишних подключенных фалов только сетка бутстрап.

Comment: Это не от margin'a а от width:40% при том что стоит display:block

Comment: Добавте код в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 2):

Тэг `<p>` по умолчанию имеет `display: block` - кирпич нужен для того, чтобы заполнить всю ширину.

Когда вы указали `width:40%` - синим вы видите это свойство, а оранжевым это тот кирпич от `display:block`